# WinJS DesiredRemainingView member of Windows.System.LauncherOptions is ignored

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have to launch, in a Windows 8 tablet, an App from my app.

So I've used the well documented method LaunchUriAsync:

```
var launchOpt = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("MyOtherApp:", launchOpt);
Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri, launchOpt);
```

The call is successfull, and MyOtherApp is opened. The problem is that is opened side-by-side with MyFirstApp (the caller).

I've found in the API documentation (and in object browser)

> public Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference
>   DesiredRemainingView { get;  set; }
>       Member of Windows.System.LauncherOptions

so I've integrated my code with the line:

```
launchOpt.DesiredRemainingView = 5;
```

(5 is the const for "useNone") before the call of LaunchUriAsync. The problem is that line is completely ignored and my apps continues to open side-by-side.
Some ideas?
Thanks, 
F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found, in winJS the correct syntax is desiredRemainingView, in camelCase (first "d" must be lower case).